# Reading layouts of other Android packages from an Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to code an Android application, that is capable of reading the layouts of other Android packages (these other packages have no relation to my application. They could be system packages, or packages from anyone else).

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? I have looked in the SDK, but was unable to find anything related to how this can be achieved.

My Android application can masquerade as the System, and has full root access. Note: This question is not about hacking or disassembling other Android applications/packages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't do it. Those files are private to the apps and you don't have the permission to read them.

Comment: Hi smith324, thanks for your response. To clarify, I have added that my Android app can masquerade as the System and has full root access.

Comment: Refer this [LINK](http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-access-resources-from-other.html) it some clear explanation how to access resources/layout of another application into our application.

Comment: Hello Agarwal, thank you for your response, but it doesn't apply to my question. I do not have source to other applications.

Comment: then what you have of that app?

Comment: Agarwal, any app, not a specific app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how to do that, but try layout inflater to inflate the layout. I think it should work.

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, package_name.R.layout.layout_id, null);
```