# Get the layout / views from another activity

Tags: android

I am creating an android application where I want to access the views/layouts of some other application.I know the package name and the Activity name of the application I need to access.

Suppose the application I need to access is "Hello World" - the package is "com.hello"  and the activity is  "com.hello.HelloWorldActivity". Now based on this information I need to find the layouts and views in the HelloWorldActivity.

Is there a way to do this.
Can someone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203042/reading-layouts-of-other-android-packages-from-an-android-app It's not possible up to my understanding.

Comment: Thank U for replying. But is there a way to get views/layout information for the same application by knowing only the package name and the activity name.I don't have any id for  layouts/views at the runtime. Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

you may watch as Android Test Projects (JUnit) have access to **same signed apps**. For example [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) may access to views of differens activities.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work.

```
View view = View.inflate(this, package_name.R.layout.layout_id, null);
```

Comment: Thank U for replying. But is there a way to get views/layout information for the same application by knowing only the package name and the activity name.I don't have any id for layouts/views at the runtime. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. The only thing you can access at runtime is SharedPreferences and this only if the developer of the other App wants you to.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't Access the Layout of another APP from one APP.